# Geometric series problem, can not get the correct result?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series, geometric-series

The number of citizens is rising in the town by the **same**/**equal** percentage each year in contrast to the previous year.
In 6 years time, the number of citizens rose from 1 635000 to 2 010000. 
What is the percentage of growth each year equal to?

My solution:

$$a_6=a_1*q^{n-1}; n=6$$
$$2 010000=1635000*q^5 => q=\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{5}5]{\frac{2010000}{1635000}}$$
and then I get: $$q=1.042$$

Can anyone help on this one..

The result should be **3.5%**

Comment: You haven't taken the 5th root. In any case it should be the sixth root.

Comment: the formula states n-1, therefore it is 5, o yes let me edit this,

Comment: There are 6 years of growth each of 3.5%.

Comment: I got it now, will post the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other way to solve this problem is through recursion:
$$T(n)=T(n-1)(1+a)$$
$$T(0)=b$$
where $b$ is the basic number of citizens and $a$ is the fraction of increase.
Now the solution of this recursion is $$b \times (1+a)^n$$
For $$T(6)=b \times (1+a)^6=2010000\implies (1+a)^6=\frac{2010000}{1635000}$$
Now solve for a.

Comment: I love this one. will mark it as the answer

Comment: There was a slight mistake in the answer, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Since 1635000 is the **non increased** value therefore it is the $a_0$ or the $a_1$ but then we add $a_7$ as the final value.

Therefore:

$$a_7=a_1*q^6 => q=1.035 => 0.035$$
That's 0.035 increase or 3.5% each year.

In other words:

$$a_1=0x\space increase=1,635000 $$
$$a_2=1x\space increase$$
$$a_3=2x\space increase$$
$$a_4=3x\space increase$$
$$a_5=4x\space increase$$
$$a_6=5x\space increase$$
$$a_7=6x\space increase=2,010000$$

Answer (score 1):

$$B=A\;(1+g)^6\\
g=\left(\frac BA\right)^\frac16-1
$$